# MongoDB installed via Homebrew not working

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I installed MongoDB via Homebrew (following http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) but it's not working.

Typing `mongod` at shell prompt gives me:

```
-bash: mongod: command not found
```

Not sure if I need to add something for Homebrew to my PATH env var?

I can see Mongo is installed under `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb` – but am assuming I don't need to add everything I install via homebrew to the path? Also, assuming I can run mongod from any directory or am I actually meant to be in install directory?

When I run `brew doctor` I get:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
```

Followed by a list of 3 items which includes MongoDB – but I'm not sure how I'm meant to link them?

Comment: More info:  I can run mongo if I execute it from its install dir within /usr/local/Cellar, but I thought I was meant to be able to run it from anywhere.  Feel like I'm missing something obvious with Homebrew.

Answer (score 20):

Works perfectly

1. `brew update`
2. `brew tap mongodb/brew`
3. `brew install mongodb-community@4.2`

For latest version, check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/

Answer (score 10):

You're getting this error because your 'brew' install failed to create the correct symlinks in /usr/local/bin.  As a result, the shell can't find the mongo executables in your $PATH.  You can fix this using the following steps:

- Check the permissions on /usr/local/bin and make sure that you own that directory and have write permissions on it

  `$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin`
- Once you've fixed that, run 'brew link' to fix the symlinks

  `$ brew link mongodb`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I chowned the folder /usr/local/bin.
If you get prompts like this:

`Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.2.2-x86_64/bin/mongotop`

You should remove the symlink first and then re-link it.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on `mongodb-community@4.0`. You can try to reinstall with `brew reinstall mongodb-community@4.0`.

Then I get the following hint:

```sh
==> Caveats
mongodb-community@4.0 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have mongodb-community@4.0 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

So you can just copy the `echo` command and restart your shell!

Comment: you also should `source` your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

Copied from a different channel running these commands in the terminal updated the installation/configuration issues as described in OP

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and this solution seemed to work for me. I had previously uninstalled mongodb and reinstalled it through homebrew which gave me a bunch of problems. This solution seemed to work just fine.

```
brew uninstall --force mongodb
```

```
brew cleanup -s mongodb
```

```
brew cleanup --prune-prefix
```

```
brew install mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

It works from the directory since the sh searches the ENV path and then the cwd for a program named mongod. I have been looking around a little and it seems that the default install of MongoDB (I am not a Mac user) does not install a rc or init script for which sh to understand it's running behaviour as stated here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#using-mongodb-from-homebrew-and-macports

> The packages installed with Homebrew and MacPorts contain no control
>   scripts or interaction with the system’s process manager.
>
> If you have configured Homebrew and MacPorts correctly, including
>   setting your PATH, the MongoDB applications and utilities will be
>   accessible from the system shell. Start the mongod process in a
>   terminal (for testing or development) or using a process management
>   tool.

So you must actually define (as you said) MongoDBs path, here is an example: https://snipt.net/sido/installing-mongodb-on-os-x/

Edit: the example is not mine. I just stole it from it's user: https://snipt.net/sido/